# How to merge different datasets with datetime index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, merge

I have two datasets (Lots and Measurements) that both have datetime indexes but different lengths and columns. The first dataset (Lots) is structured as follows:

| Datetime Index | Lot Group | Lot No | Booking Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-08-03 10:00:00 | 1 | 261291.0 | PROB1H |
| 2013-08-03 12:00:00 | 1 | 261228.0 | PROB1H |

The other one (Measurements) is structured as follows:

| Datetime Index | MID | Passed? | Measurement1 | Measurement2 | Measurement3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-08-28 10:00:00 | 12345 | True | 46.908 | 3.89 | 29.056 |
| 2013-08-03 12:00:00 | 78262 | True | 89.457 | 6.88 | 34.918 |

What I am trying to do is merge the two dataframes on the datetime index and get all the columns in both dataframes and if there is a match on the datetime index it would add the MID, Passed? and measurement columns to the Lots dataframeand would also keep the duplicates if there are any and would also keep missing values as NaNs for example:

Let's say the datetime 2013-08-28 10:00:00 is not present in the Lots dataframe but is present in the Measurement dataframe so that would produce:

| Datetime Index | Lot Group | Lot No | Booking Level | MID | Passed? | Measurement1 | Measurement2 | Measurement3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-08-28 10:00:00 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 12345 | True | 46.908 | 3.89 | 29.056 |

and if there is a match for example in the datetime  2013-08-03 12:00:00 it would produce:

| Datetime Index | Lot Group | Lot No | Booking Level | MID | Passed? | Measurement1 | Measurement2 | Measurement3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-08-03 12:00:00 | 1 | 261228.0 | PROB1H | 78262 | True | 89.457 | 6.88 | 34.918 |

The Lots dataframe's datetime index has only unique datetime values but the Measurement dataframe there are duplicate entries so if there is a match with a duplicate entry I would like to get duplicate rows for example:

Let's say the datetime 2021-04-15 22:00:00 is present in both dataframes but is found multiple times in the Measurement dataframe so it would produce the following:

| Datetime Index | Lot Group | Lot No | Booking Level | MID | Passed? | Measurement1 | Measurement2 | Measurement3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-15 22:00:00 | 2 | 311000.0 | PROB2H | 34903 | True | 39 | 67 | 50 |
| 2021-04-15 22:00:00 | 2 | 311000.0 | PROB2H | 34904 | True | 88 | 40.90 | 54.38 |

I have tried different merging but couldn't get the result I wanted I tried:

```py
test = lots.merge(measurement, how = "right",left_index=True, right_index=True)
test2 = lots.merge(measurement, how = "outer",left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

How would you suggest I go about this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` as well as `merge`:

```
# Dataset Lots
>>> dfL
                     Lot Group    Lot No Booking Level
Datetime Index                                        
2013-08-03 10:00:00          1  261291.0        PROB1H
2013-08-03 12:00:00          1  261228.0        PROB1H
2021-04-15 22:00:00          2  311000.0        PROB2H

# Dataset Measurements
>>> dfM
                       MID  Passed?  Measurement1  Measurement2  Measurement3
Datetime Index                                                               
2013-08-28 10:00:00  12345     True        46.908          3.89        29.056
2013-08-03 12:00:00  78262     True        89.457          6.88        34.918
2021-04-15 22:00:00  34903     True        39.000         67.00        50.000
2021-04-15 22:00:00  34904     True        88.000         40.90        54.380

# Join version
>>> dfL.join(dfM, how='outer')
                     Datetime Index  Lot Group Lot No Booking Level      MID Passed?  Measurement1  Measurement2  Measurement3
2013-08-03 10:00:00             1.0   261291.0               PROB1H      NaN     NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
2013-08-03 12:00:00             1.0   261228.0               PROB1H  78262.0    True        89.457          6.88        34.918
2013-08-28 10:00:00             NaN        NaN                  NaN  12345.0    True        46.908          3.89        29.056
2021-04-15 22:00:00             2.0   311000.0               PROB2H  34903.0    True        39.000         67.00        50.000
2021-04-15 22:00:00             2.0   311000.0               PROB2H  34904.0    True        88.000         40.90        54.380

# Merge version
>>> dfL.merge(dfM, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
                     Datetime Index  Lot Group Lot No Booking Level      MID Passed?  Measurement1  Measurement2  Measurement3
2013-08-03 10:00:00             1.0   261291.0               PROB1H      NaN     NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
2013-08-03 12:00:00             1.0   261228.0               PROB1H  78262.0    True        89.457          6.88        34.918
2013-08-28 10:00:00             NaN        NaN                  NaN  12345.0    True        46.908          3.89        29.056
2021-04-15 22:00:00             2.0   311000.0               PROB2H  34903.0    True        39.000         67.00        50.000
2021-04-15 22:00:00             2.0   311000.0               PROB2H  34904.0    True        88.000         40.90        54.380
```

Comment: @MohamedArebi. Can you check if the answer below is the expected outcome, please?

Comment: Yes it is 90% what I expected to output but what I also wanted was to ouput the date '2013-08-03 10:00:00' with all the data from the lots dataframe but NaNs for the other dataframe

Comment: @MohamedArebi. I updated my answer. This is what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Your `merge` attempts are close.

```
test2 = lots.merge(measurements, how='right', on='Datetime Index')

print(test2)

    Datetime Index  Lot Group    Lot No Booking Level    MID  Passed?  Measurement1  Measurement2  Measurement3
0 2013-08-28 10:00:00        NaN       NaN           NaN  12345     True        46.908          3.89        29.056
1 2013-08-03 12:00:00        1.0  261228.0        PROB1H  78262     True        89.457          6.88        34.918
```

This example still works if you omit `on='Datetime Index'`, though it's probably better to keep it to show intent. From [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

> If `on` is `None` and not merging on indexes then [merge] defaults to the
> intersection of the columns in both DataFrames.

Comment: I think '2013-08-03 10:00:00' should not appear in the final outcome?

Comment: But the Datetime Index is not a column it is an index present in both dataframes, would that work as well? Or the on can be an index level name?

Comment: @MohamedArebi apologies, I didn't read the fact that `Datetime Index` (as its name hints) is in fact a `DatetimeIndex` :) Based on your comment in the other answer, it seems that your second attempt, `lots.merge(measurement, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)`, should do exactly what you want. Does that still not produce your expected result?